# Problem when switching pages in Laravel + VUE

Tags: laravel, vue-router

When switching to other pages without reloading, the layout of the site is displayed incorrectly. But if you refresh the page, the layout is displayed correctly. I use vue-router.

```
<router-link :to="('/u/' + list.author.username)" class="entry_header__subsite__author l-mr-23 lm-mr-0">{{ list.author.username }}</router-link>
```

Site on which the problem https://ain.today

What is the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: this question is too broad and has too little info

Comment: What information need more? I give information, just i dont can understand where have problem for give information code

Comment: you cannot derive the error from the code you give. In addition the link you gave does not work...